# How to interpret the values of the inertia matrix?

Tags: angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

I've a foldable quadrotor with rotating arms.
So, the quadrotor can take different morphologies, like the classical one "X", an "H" morphology, "Y", etc.
I've calculated the inertia matrix for each one, but I couldn't interpret why $I_{xx}$ is higher than $I_{yy}$ in some morphologies and the inverse in others.

To simplify the problem we talk about the "H" morphology

```
|__|
|  |
```

It's a symmetric morphology, where I found that $I_{yy}>I_{xx}$, knowing that the $x$-axis is directed upwards.
The $y$-axis is directed to the left and the $z$-axis is perpendicular to the  screen.

Why is $I_{yy}>I_{xx}$?

Comment: Because there is more mass, and greater distance from the center in the $y$ direction?

Comment: Do you mean "interpret" rather than "interrupt?"

Comment: to interpret, so there is a relation between distance and inertia, please can you give me this mathematic expression and it will be better if u cite an article . Thank you soo much

Answer (score 0):

When you see the y axis which passes through the middle of H . The big arms are far from the axis so moment of inertia is higher as momentum of interia is proportional to square of distance

Comment: Great, what is the mathematical relation between inertia and distance , 2) if there is a book or article wich express that to cite it.?